# AngularJS LocalStorageModule is not available

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to get a brand new Ionic project working with angular-local-storage with no luck. I'm somehow referencing angular-local-storage incorrectly, but I don't know how.

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic platform add ios
ionic build ios
bower install angular-local-storage

// app.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'LocalStorageModule'])
```

Then

```
ionic serve
```

Error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LocalStorageModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'LocalStorageModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: I'd make sure that you have the `<script>` tag in your `index.html`

Comment: @duffn what is the script tag i should  add in my index.html can you send me the tag to be added or to be reffered in index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ionic, but it looks to me like you're missing the script.

Are you sure that you have the script included on the page?  I'd confirm that bower did indeed install the script where you think it should be and then make sure its actually referenced before this error is thrown.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Guy should need to check that have you added link to it's script

```
src="https://rawgit.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/master/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"
```

using `<script></script>` tag in your index file. It might be the issue. For the guys who will see this in future.